# Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Geocoder.GetPositionsForAddressAsync Getting Exception from HRESULT: 0x80041B56

Tags: xamarin, maps

I have implemented the `public Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable> GetAddressesForPositionAsync(Position position);` method to retrieve the coordinates for given addresses. This method is being called for multiple address. I get the exception from the application, if user click on a link in our application and navigate to browser while the address are being processed. I have looked into windows documentation for this error code. The documentation says that we need to handle eErrorCancelled code. Please let me know, how to handle this when using `Xamarin.Forms.Maps`

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80041B56
>
> {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80041B56): Exception from HRESULT: 0x80041B56}
> Tagged: Xamarin.Forms.Maps GetPositionsForAddressAsync

Comment: This is when running on Windows Phone platform, correct (Xamarin.Forms WinPhone)?

Comment: Yes, this is not working on windows phone